# Google datastudio : chart style

Tags: looker-studio

Today we have many google data studio reports, we manually style the report charts by using chart options like tableheader, tablefooter, ...).

Someone in the company asked me if we can reuse styling over reports instead of defining it each time again. By using this colab notebook (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/community-visualization#0) we could build a simple bar chart with a CSS. However we do not have the need to build the chart by our self (community visualization with defined java script).

My question
Is it possible to define the style of the 'out of the box' google data studio reports in a way that it is reusable over different reports instead of doing it manually into each report? According my investigation I would conclude that this is not possible, however I would like to be sure before I communicate this into the company.

Thx

Comment: Couldn't you create an empty report to serve as a template and make a copy of it every time you need a new report?

Comment: Thx for the info, this could indeed be an option to help people that want to design google data studio reports.